# Prevent prompt "...index.html" Would like to use your current location in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, build, phonegap

I am using Phonegap Build for my iOS app and get the ugly prompt for access to geolocation API.

There seems to be many fixes and none of them solved my issue. What I have currently - which does not fix it is:

- phonegap.js as first script loaded
- geolocation not fired before device is ready
- all js files together in the root
- changed plugin from phonegap to cordova

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry for being unspecific. The question is: How do I change the prompt for using geolocation from showing the local storage path of the index.html into - perhaps - the app title or at least something nicer.

Comment: I think it depends of the plugin. I use these plugins https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation and https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps and don't have the index-html title.

Comment: you have to install geolocation plugin

Comment: I'm using this one:
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" />

Answer (score 0):

The user @kaae is correct-- if you call the geolocation functions before the device is ready, the natural browser alert prompt will show instead of being handled by the plugin.

Although you have stated "geolocation not fired before device is ready" the fact that you're seeing that native browser prompt means that it is.

You can have the geolocation functions outside, but the call to them should be inside:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() { [CALL TO FUNCTION HERE] }
```

Since this question is number one on Google, I felt the need to comment for others using ionic or cordova and having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To change the prompt you just need to update geolocation plugin. In my case when I updated cordova-plugin-geolocation prompt containing index.html path disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

This fix was to wait setting up the geolocation callbacks till later in the flow.